# How to convert function with LiveData to implement/convert in Flow?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

Here is the extension function on LiveData, how can I implement with Kotlin Flow?

```
private fun <A, B, C : Any> LiveData<A>.mergeWith(
    other: LiveData<B>,
    merger: (A?, B?) -> C,
): LiveData<C> {
    val liveData = MediatorLiveData<C>()
    liveData.addSource(this) { a ->
        liveData.value = merger(a, other.value)
    }
    liveData.addSource(other) { b ->
        liveData.value = merger(value, b)
    }
    liveData.value = merger(value, other.value)
    return liveData
}
```

Comment: Could you have a go at this conversion? That might encourage more readers to give you pointers that will help you complete it.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the `combine` function from `kotlinx.flow` to achieve the same result. Please find the example use case [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/combine.html).

```kotlin
fun <T1, T2, R> Flow<T1>.combine(
    flow: Flow<T2>, 
    transform: suspend (a: T1, b: T2) -> R
): Flow<R>
```

Comment: but it isn't the same as combine, right?